# Hiding overlay div styled using adjacent sibling combinator in IE (9, 10 and 11)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have the following CSS style for a overlay (hovering) div to prevent user interaction. The logic behind the styling is that when the div with `indicator` class is displayed then overlay is also displayed. When the div with `indicator` class hides using `display: none`, then the overlay has to be hided. This style works fine in Chrome and Firfox. But in IE overlay div hides only when moving the mouse. Sometimes a small movement is enough. Other times, it has to be moved out of the overlay div (note: overlay div actually don't hide the whole page). How can I hide overlay div without moving the mouse in IE?

```
div[id*='someDivId'] .indicator + .layout .overlay {
    background: #e9e9e9 url(img/spinner.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: 40001;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    pointer-events: inherit;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

div[id*='someDivId'] .indicator[style*="none"] + .layout .overlay {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Please find below an overview of html elements structure

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- header contents -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="someDivId1234567">
            <div class="indicator">
                <!-- loading indicator -->
            </div>
            <div class="layout">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div>
                    <!-- contents -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add the HTML to your question too?

Comment: @ovokuro - I have added html to the question. Due to some restrictions it is not possible to rearrange it in my context.